# How to plot all nodes in a graph using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a graph in MATLAB with lots of unconnected nodes, from a matrix.
When I use the following commands:

```
A=graph(B); %B is the matrix i want to plot
plot(A);
```

Most of the nodes are missing in the figure. I wonder whether there is a way for me to plot all the nodes in one figure.

Comment: What are the dimensions of B and how many nodes you get in the display?

Comment: What you are saying is that `A` doesn’t represent your graph. Did you read the documentstion to see how `B` is interpreted? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html — in short, the graph is given by edges, not by nodes. Unconnected nodes cannot exist!